# redirect visitor in function of his ip adress (client side)

Tags: xpages

I would like to redirect the visitor of my Xpage depending on the country of his ip adress.
So when the visitor comes from france he should be redirected to france.xsp , Germany to germany.xsp etc.
I think this should be possible with : [Geo ip API](http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api)

I have no idea how to implement it, or maybe somebody has a better solution for this ?

edit : 
Since this page already loads Jquery I took the solution from Alexandro , which I 've put in the on client load event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a free website to do this, http://freegeoip.net/

You can do a JSON request at http://freegeoip.net/json/ and you can use the returned data, for example using jQuery to do it on client side:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
  // If the visitor is browsing from Canada.
  if (location.country_code == 'CA') {
    // Redirect him to the canadian store.
    window.location.href = 'http://shop-in-canada.com';
  }
});
```

For more information on getJSON method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I already loaded Jquery for this page so I used this solution which works fine. I've put it in the on client load event. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The website in Alesanco's answer is a great resource, but if you want to do this without using jQuery libraries, here's how you can do it in Dojo without having to add anything else to your XPage.

```
require(['dojo/_base/xhr'], function(xhr){
  xhr.get({
    url:"http://freegeoip.net/json/", handleAs:"json",
    load: function(data){
      // data is a JavaScript object. The content of foo.php
      // was passed through dojo.fromJson
      alert(data.country_code); //Returns the country code. Use this to drive your logic.
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Domino 9 (with IBM Http Server installed in front of Domino), or if you are using a Web Server like Apache or Nginx in front of Domino, you can use modules like:

- https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-mod_geoip2 - Apache 2 GeoIP module
- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoipModule - Nginx GeoIP module

This way you will not depend on hard-coding the check